# How to connect Matek H743 FC to Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: quadcopters, raspberry-pi, fc-firmware

I am using INAV firmware with Matek H743 FC. I want to connect FC to Raspberry Pi and read data from lidar/optical flow and GPS sensors.
Culd you please provide me with documentation ? I dont know where to start. I have found how to connect Raspberry PI to FC on Ardupilot docs [here](https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/raspberry-pi-via-mavlink.html) . But it is about Ardupilot and I want to use INAV.
Apart from that, if you have a solution for Betaflight - it will be good as well.
I dont know which libraries I need to use in order to read data from FC. Hence two questions:

1. How to wire (connect) FC and Raspberry (pin map) ?
2. How to connect them programmatically on Raspberry PI side ?

Thank you